# Spring MVC 3.1 - Namespace error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following in my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">
```

The XML validation fails saying

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'context:component-scan'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":argument-resolvers, "http://www.springframework.org/
>    schema/mvc":return-value-handlers}' is expected.

I have checked the schemas defined in 
 `http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/` and everything seems to be fine.  Previously I was using Spring mvc 3.0 and it did not face any problem. I have all my jar files directly in `WEB-INF/lib`.  Any ideas?

**Update**

This is the line where the validation fails `<context:component-scan base-package="com" />`and yes all the jars used are from Spring 3.1

Comment: Are all the jars of version 3.1?

Comment: @skaffman: Have updated the question to provide the info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could be wrong, but looking at the schemas and the error given, are you perhaps trying to place the `<context:component-scan base-package="com" />` -element within `<mvc:annotation-driven> </mvc:annotation-driven>` -tags or forgetting to close the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` -tag? Place the component-scan outside the tags or close the `<mvc:annotation-driven>` -tag properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I had forgotten to close the <mvc:annotation-driven>. Silly me. I had been trying to figure out what the problem was for more than half an hour. Got to get my eye checked :P